# VBA: Run type error 13 type mismatch / SUMIF function with not exact match

Tags: excel, vba, sumifs, exact-match

I have been looking for a while now at my code and cannot find the reason why I get the run type error. I am trying to use the SUMIF function without exact match (I use *). Please help guys. Hope its clear. Many thanks!!

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Range("AB10").Formula = "=SUMIF('" & vbaPath & vbaFile & vbasheet & "'!B:B,C10&" * ", '" & vbaPath & vbaFile & vbasheet & "'!P:P)"
```

Comment: I don't see the sheet name in there ? I assume `vbaPath` means the path and `vbaFile` means the worknook name, but you also need the sheet's name

Comment: Hi Shai. thanks for your quick reply and for spotting the error. I changed it to the following but still get the same error?

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Range("AB10").Formula = "=SUMIF('" & vbaPath & vbaFile & vbasheet  & "'!B:B,C10&" * ", '" & vbaPath & vbaFile & vbasheet & "'!P:P)"

Comment: The syntax highlighting above tells you that you are multiplying `"'!B:B,C10&"` and `", '"`.

Comment: There will need to be `[]` in there and some extra `/`  without seeing how you assign the value to the variables it is hard for us to know the problem.

Comment: You also need to remove the spaces around the `*` and add `"`  so `""*""`.

Comment: Hi Scott! Thanks for your reply and for your help. I have assigned the value of the variables including [] and / . You were right regarding the extra " (""*""), thanks for spotting. Unfortunatley I have somewhere else a small error as I get a #value! error in the cell. (the defined variables are fine because I use them for different cells without problems). You have any other suggestion? Thanks again for your help, greatly appreciated!

Comment: EDIT: Strangely when I remove the path (Y:\...) it works! However I use the same path for all my vlookups in the workbook. Is there a difference between paths in SUMIF and VLOOKUPS? Thanks again!